# How would I display HealthKit Data in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am messing around with HealthKit and I just want to make a very simple app to just read the number of ActiveCaloriesBurned from HealthKit and print it onto the ViewController. I am unsure if I am accessing the data properly in my HealthManager class, and I am also unsure how to properly call the healthKit data to print in my viewController.

I know I have to create a class where I verify that the user allows the app to access healthKit data. So first I created a class called HealthManager to tackle my first problem of verification, which I am sure works properly:

```
class HealthManager {

    let storage = HKHealthStore()

    init()
    {
        checkAuthorization()
    }

    func checkAuthorization() -> Bool {
        var isEnabled = true

        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {

            // Explicitly requests calorie data
            let calories = NSSet(object: HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!)

            // Requests authorization for calorie data
            storage.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(nil, readTypes: calories as? Set<HKObjectType>) { (success, error) -> Void in
                isEnabled = success
            }
        }

        else {
            isEnabled = false
        }

        return isEnabled

    }

}
```

But I don't know what to do next. Where and how do I read the ActiveCaloriesBurned inside my current class? And where would I go about returning the value as a string and how would I pass all this information into my viewController?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can access following information using Health Kit.
 - DateOfBirth
 - BloodType
 - BiologicalSex
 - BodyMass
 - Height
 - WorkoutType

I think best to create new independent "HelathKitHelper" singleton class and write all logic in this class.

Through it you can call same code using different-2 controller classes.

Some tutorial link http://natashatherobot.com/healthkit-getting-fitness-data/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you I will definitely try it out! How would I call this said singleton class back in my viewController to get it to print out onto the screen?

Comment: You can create model class for data and store all required health related information in the model class.
you can create some method like - (ModelClass*) getData; in the singleton class and call this method from view controller.

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented something similar in our HealthKit bridge that we built for our personal data middleware Pryv.
We've tested it in a sample app, that allows the user to authorize other apps to read/write data to Apple HealthKit and to display it.
You can find the code here: https://github.com/pryv/app-ios-swift-example.
Our middleware for personal data collection and consent management is open-source, so feel free to use it, along with our sample apps: https://github.com/pryv/open-pryv.io